# Recommende e commerce plugin for simple needs

Tags: plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

I want to create a small ecommerce functionality for my site.
Namely 4 products, payment via a Bank portal gateway.
Nothing more.
Which plugin do you recommend for such simple needs?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce is a very good option with a multitude of gateways available.

I've used it on quite a few setups and have been very pleased with the results.